# Next JS deployment on Apache Server

Tags: javascript, linux, apache, centos, next.js

I am trying to get my Next JS project working on an apache server and have difficulties doing that. Am not sure how I should set the root path alias and the reverse proxy like I did in Nginx?!

If I understood it correctly then I would need to set the alias on the /.next folder where Next is building the app. For Nginx I was following this tutorial: https://www.willandskill.se/en/setup-a-next-js-project-with-pm2-nginx-and-yarn-on-ubuntu-18-04/

How can i achieve exactly the same functionality with apache? Should it be used like described in this post in cunjunction with Nginx?[How can I make my nextjs with Express site work on ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239694/how-can-i-make-my-nextjs-with-express-site-work-on-ssl)

And should a .htaccess file being used with apache and next js?

I would appreciate some feedback on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey, I know its been almost 3 years but am trying to do the same, any tips for me? thanks in advance

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm